# Concatenating string with nested variables to provide proper behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have following line that is hard to write properly:

```
 document.write('<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset"'+
            ' type="button"'+ 
            'onClick="addToBasket(\'' + 
            +JSON.stringify(products[i]) +  
             '\')"/></td>');
        document.write("</tr>");
```

There is a rule js strings are not spreading on a new line and it must be like that. But there maybe mistake occured somewhere?

Comment: Hi there, what is your desired output from this line?

Comment: Check out template literals for JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: you can simply store long string value in new variable and reference that variable

Comment: you concatenate `type="button"` to `onClick=` and there is no space between them.

Comment: Also, "*There is a rule js strings are not spreading on a new line and it must be like that. But there maybe mistake occured somewhere?*" for these reasons and more, you should be *avoiding* producing code from strings. Be that HTML code or JS, or whatever. It's a very bad practice and a small mistake is a very real possibility. Moreover, maintainability is very very hard and a lot of tools worn't even properly work on strings, as a basic example - syntax highlighting in your editor of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to concatenate:

```
document.write(`<td><input value="Add to ShopBakset"
             type="button" 
            onClick="addToBasket(${JSON.stringify(products[i])})"/></td>`);
document.write("</tr>");
```

Comment: unexpected end of input in line </script>